# Overriding HttpServlet service method

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet which looks like :

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             throws IOException, ServletException {
    doTheJob(request, response);
}//method doGet

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
              throws IOException, ServletException {
    doTheJob(request, response);
}//method doPost

private void doTheJob(.....) {
    ...........................
}

}
```

Because of the way my application works, I only need to call **doTheJob()** both from **doGet()** and from **doPost()**. So I think, I better override the method **service()** of the **HttpServlet**.

But I would like to know if that will brake anything or will cause any issues.

Comment: The real answer depends on the *why* you need to do perform the same job on both GET and POST. Are you designing a front controller servlet or so? What exactly is this servlet supposed to do/represent?

Comment: well, thats my one and only one Controller of an MVC style arch. Now, why I am doing it that way is, my app is designed in such a way that it will send all the necessary params {query string, form data etc,} in order to identify/understand what the App is supposed to do. So the method **doTheJob** can make out that without having to know whether or not the request was actually a GET or POST.

Answer (score 24):

This is how `service()` is typically implemented ([very simplified](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/3.0-alpha-1/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java#HttpServlet.service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)):

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String method = req.getMethod();

    if (method.equals(METHOD_GET)) {
            doGet(req, resp);
    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_HEAD)) {
        doHead(req, resp);
    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_POST)) {
        doPost(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_PUT)) {
        doPut(req, resp);   

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_DELETE)) {
        doDelete(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_OPTIONS)) {
        doOptions(req,resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_TRACE)) {
        doTrace(req,resp);

    } else {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, errMsg);
    }
}
```

As you can see it barely delegates to `doGet()` and `doPost()` depending on HTTP method. So from one hand replacing `doGet()` and `doPost()` with `service()` is fine. On the other hand your servlet will also handle `PUT`, `DELETE`, `HEAD` and other methods while with separate `doGet()` and `doPost()` it will return *405 Method not allowed*.

That's why I would actually advice separate `doGet()` and `doPost()` delegating to your code and let servlet handle other methods. If this is a recurring pattern in your code, consider the following helper servlet:

```
public class AbstractServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                 throws IOException, ServletException {
        doGetOrPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                  throws IOException, ServletException {
        doGetOrPost(request, response);
    }

    abstract protected void doGetOrPost(.....);

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You'd better keep it as it is. Overriding the `service()` method also makes this method answer to PUT, HEAD, DELETE, etc. And it bypasses the work the default `service()` method does with last-modified headers.