# Passing values from servlet to JSP - null value is received at the JSP page.

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to pass two values (`intMethod` and `SpotDays`) from `SourceServlet` to a JSP named `CcySorting.jsp`.

I am using the `setRequestAttribute()` method to set the values at servlet end and using `getRequestAttribute()` at JSP end to receive the values. But I am receiving null values in JSP. My code is below. Please have a look at it and suggest the possible reason. I have tried a lot, but in vain.

I am also providing my JSP and servlet folder structure.

**My folder structure:**

- JSP path: `application.war\CcySorting.jsp`
- Servlet path: `application.war\WEB-INF\classes\SampleServlet.class`

**My entries in `Web.xml`:**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>SampleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/SampleServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**My JSP Files:**

- *CcySorting.jsp*

  ```
  function searchData(brn,ccy)
  {
      var frmObj  =getUserFormObj('window','div0','form0');
      window.open("/SampleServlet?BrnName="+brn+"&Currency="+ccy);    
      var intMethod= <%= request.getAttribute("intMethod1") %>;
      var spotDay = <%= request.getAttribute("SpotDays1") %>;
      alert("data from servlet"+intMethod+"and spot"+spotDay1);
  }
  ```
- *SampleServlet.java*

  ```
  public class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet{     

      public void service(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException{

          // Some code to fetch the data from database and store in two variable intm and spot
          int int=2
          int spot=3              
          request.setAttribute("intMethod1",int);
          request.setAttribute("SpotDays1", spot);
          RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/CcySorting.jsp");
          rd.forward( request, response ) ;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: As a side note: [**using scriplets in JSP is highly discouraged**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702). You hardly ever need to override `service()` method: just override more concrete `doXXX()`method. Read here: [**Should I override service() method?**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6822041/814702)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. that seems  everything correct other than retrieving data :

change your `jsp` receivers to :

```
var intMethod= '<%= request.getAttribute("intMethod1") %>';
var spotDay = '<%= request.getAttribute("SpotDays1") %>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using scriplets is not encouraged. You can try using this in your JS function.

```
var intmethod='${intmethod1}';
var spotday='${SpotDays1}';
```

Also try scriplets in your HTML section and see what values are you retrieving.

```
intmethod=<%= request.getAttribute("intMethod1")%>;
spotsday=<%= request.getAttribute("SpotDays1") %>;
```