# RESTEasy - Best practices to override service method to implement some generic logic across the different methods (like in servlet)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, resteasy

Ex: I have some common logic across different resources

```
@Path("/rest")
public class AddUser {

   @GET
   @Path("/AddUser/{ext}/{userId}")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String addUser(@PathParam("tenantId") String tenantId, @PathParam("userId") Integer userId) {

   //I have some common logic here

}


@Path("/newrest")
public class AddUser1 {   
    @GET
    @Path("/AddUser/{ext}/{userId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String addDifferentUser(@PathParam("tenantId") String tenantId,              @PathParam("userId") Integer userId) {

      //I have same common logic here as well
  }

}
```

Which class i can extend to overwrite common logic for bot the rest services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding Service method is not recommended [Should I override service ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822006/should-i-override-service-or-dopost)

Take a look @ [ContainerRequestFilter](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) An extension interface implemented by container request filters. You can handle your common logic here.

Comment: Thanks Gopidoss for your answer. Please can you give some sample code for implementation.

Comment: Check this link for implementation (http://howtodoinjava.com/resteasy/jax-rs-2-0-resteasy-3-0-2-final-security-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not have bussiness logic directly in the communication layer. Imagine adding soap interface using different technology it will be imposible to use any common entry point.

You'd rather write service class and call it wherever you need.

Comment: He's using a REST API, so he will not be adding SOAP. You better delete this post.